# How to check if each file in a path is accessible for reading or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, readdir

I am trying to read the contents of a specific path. for that purpose, i used the following code:

**code1**:

```
const contentsOfPersonalFolder = fs.readdirSync(rootPathToPersonal);
```

but i know in advance that i do not have access permission to read some of the contents that will be returned from the previous line of code.
To check whether or not I have access permission to read some files, i would use the following code

**code2**:

```
try {
  fs.accessSync(path, fs.constants.R_OK);
  logger.info('The directory: ', path, 'can be read');
} catch (err) {
  logger.error('The directory: ', path, 'can not be read due inaccessibility');
}
```

The problem now is, the code in code1 will return an array of all available files in the specified path. and if one of the these files is not 
accessible due read right protection, then it will throw and the program will throw.

what i want to achieve is to iterate through all the available files in the specified path in code1, and then check each item using the code in code2 and 
if the file is accessible for reading i would like to do some logic, and if it is not accessible for reading i would do something else.

please let me know how to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

you could use fs.access to check the users permissions
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback

```
const testFolder = './tests/';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
    fs.access(file, fs.constants.R_OK, (err) => {
        if (err) { 
            console.error("file is not readable");
            return;
        }

        // do your reading operations
    });
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');

const isAvailableToRead = file => {
  try {
    fs.accessSync(file, fs.constants.R_OK);
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}

const readDirectory = path => {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(path);
  files.forEach(file => {
    if(isAvailableToRead(file)) {
      console.log(`Do some logic ${file}`);
    }
  });
}

readDirectory(__dirname);
```